# Contributions of each feature in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have some features and I am using Weka to classify my instances.

For example I have:

`Number of adj   number of adverb    number of punctuation`

in my feature set. However, I would like to know the contribution of each feature in the feature set. So what metrics or parameters are helpful to get the contribution of features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called feature ranking, which is closely related to [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection).

- feature ranking = determining the importance of any individual feature
- feature selection = selecting a subset of relevant features for use in model construction.

So if you are able to ranked features, you can use it to select features, and if you can select a subset of useful features, you've done at least a partial ranking by removing the useless ones.

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) and this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-perform-feature-selection?share=1) should give some ideas. The distinction filter methods vs. wrapper based methods vs. embedded methods is the most common one.

---

One straightforward approximate way is to use [feature importance with forests of trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html):

[image]

Other common ways:

- [recursive feature elimination](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html).
- stepwise regression (or [LARS Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#lars-lasso)).

If you use scikit-learn, check out [module-sklearn.feature_selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection). I'd guess Weka has some similar functions.