# How to determine feature importance while using xgboost in pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

How to determine feature importance while using xgboost (`XGBclassifier` or `XGBregressor`) in pipeline?

```
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'get_fscore'
```

The answer provided [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6683/feature-selection-using-feature-importances-in-random-forests-with-scikit-learn) is similar but I couldn't get the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I found, there are two ways to determine feature importance:
First:

```
print(grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps["clf"].feature_importances_)
```

result:

```
[ 0.14582562  0.08367272  0.06409663  0.07631433  0.08705109  0.03827286
  0.0592836   0.05025916  0.07076083  0.0699278   0.04993521  0.07756387
  0.05095335  0.07608293]
```

Second:

```
print(grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps["clf"].booster().get_fscore())
```

result:

```
{'f2': 1385, 'f11': 1676, 'f12': 1101, 'f6': 1281, 'f9': 1511, 'f7': 1086, 'f5': 827, 'f0': 3151, 'f10': 1079, 'f1': 1808, 'f3': 1649, 'f13': 1644, 'f8': 1529, 'f4': 1881}
```

Third:

```
print(grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps["clf"].get_booster().get_fscore())
```

Comment: the problem I found is that the resultant feature names were not present in the training data itself. I had obviously renamed the f2 to the X2. Did you face such an issue ?

Comment: @fixxxer First, I am so sorry for being late. Then, in the above example, my features don't have names so the result is reported by f1, f2, and etc. However, If I use some specific names there is no problem. For example, I do this: `ln=X.shape`. `names = ["x%s" % i for i in range(1,ln[1]+1)]`. `print(sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 4), grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps["clf"].feature_importances_),names), reverse=True))`.

Comment: Thank @ebrahmi. It's an issue with the Sklearn wrapper that the feature names are not present through an API. So, what worked for me is that I had to do this to get the exact column names - `dict(zip(t.feature_names, train.columns))`

Comment: @fixxxer Could you please let me know how to print sorted features in conjunction with their names. Next, select the five features with the most feature importance. For example, f1:20, f5:17, f7:14, f10:13,f6:10, f3:8, ... 

and then, f1, f5, f7, f10, f6

Answer (score 2):

## Getting a reference to the xgboost object

You should first get the `XGBClassifier` or `XGBRegressor` element from the pipeline. You could do this either by getting the n-th element or by specifying the name.

```
clf = XGBClassifier()
pipe = Pipeline([('other', other_element), ('xgboost', clf)])
```

To get the `XGBClassifier` you could either:

- use `clf` if you still have a reference to it
- index the pipeline by name:  `pipe.named_steps['xgboost']`
- index the pipeline by location: `pipe.steps[1]`

## Getting the importance

Secondly, it seems that importance is not implemented for the sklearn implementation of xgboost. See [this github issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/757). A solution to add this to your `XGBClassifier` or `XGBRegressor` is also offered over their. It boils down to adding the methods to the class yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Does 'feature_importances_' do the same as 'get_fscore'? Here (stackoverflow.com/questions/38212649/…) 'feature_importances_' is used.@ Pieter

Comment: If you look at the code you see that it uses `get_fscore()` internally